# Getting raw request alongside body's text in express

Tags: node.js, http, express

I have an express application which deals with post request body like this:

```
var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.text({ type: "*/*" }));

app.post(url, function(req, res) {
    //Process req.body, handle the errors along the way;
});
```

Now if some error happens, I want to be able to log the whole request. By that, I mean headers, body, and everything. As if you are looking at the request using wireshark.

Does anyone know what is the easiest way to do this?

Here's an example HTTP POST request (taken from [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/POST)):

```
POST / HTTP/1.1
Host: foo.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 13

say=Hi&to=Mom
```

I need to have this when I face an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [error-handling middleware](https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html) :

```
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {

    // define log format, for example:
    let data = `URL: ${req.originalUrl} - method: ${req.method} - error: ${err.message}`;

    // append to log file
    fs.appendFile('server.log', data, function (err) {

        if (err) throw err;

        // terminate the request/response cycle
        res.status(err.status || 500);
        res.json({ error: err });

    });

});
```

Jump to error-handling middleware by calling `next(err)`, example:

```
app.get('some/route', function (req, res, next) {

    someFunction( req.body, function (err) {

        // pass err object to the error middleware
        if (err) return next(err);

        return res.json({ success: true });

    });

});
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the post but your answer does not say how can I come by the original request. That's all I care about. No error message, no response status code, just pure raw received request.

Comment: What do you mean by original request?

Comment: I think `req.originalUrl` will return the request url

Comment: Original request: A text representation of the request including headers, host, body, and whatever originally was sent to the web server (express here) before any process is done over it.

Comment: The `req` object has a lot of methods, you can use for example `req.hostname` to get request host, `req.ip` to get the ip,  `req.protocol`... here is a [link](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req) from the docs, the provided answer was just an example you could store what ever you want in the log file

Answer (score 4):

Since there aren't any actual answers here to the question of how to see the original request—headers, body, and all—I'll chip in my two cents.

The short answer is: you can't. Express doesn't make that available, and the underlying Node `http` module [doesn't either](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_incomingmessage).

The longer answer is: you can reconstruct it to some extent. You can access the raw headers of the request and reassemble them into raw text. You can also read raw payload data from the socket as it comes in and save that to a property on `req`, then use that once the data has sent. That might not get you the exact incoming message, but it will get you close. You can do this in a bit of middleware:

```
server.use((req, res, next) => {
    let data = '';
    req.on('data', (chunk) => {
        data += chunk;
    });
    req.on('end', () => {
        req.rawBody = data;
        let headers = [`${req.method} ${req.url} HTTP/${req.httpVersion}`];
        for (let i = 0; i < req.rawHeaders.length; i += 2) {
            headers.push(`${req.rawHeaders[i]}: ${req.rawHeaders[i + 1]}`);
        }
        req.rawRequest = `${headers.join('\r\n')}\r\n\r\n${req.rawBody}`;
        console.log(`Socket received data:\n\n${req.rawRequest}`);
    });
    next();
});
```

Comment: for me at least it seems that `req.on('data')` seems to interfere with later middleware...the response never goes through

Answer (score 1):

express has a great middleware for logging requests called [morgan](https://github.com/expressjs/morgan)
you can define your own custom log format

```
var morgan = require('morgan')
morgan(function (tokens, req, res) {
  return [
    tokens.method(req, res),
    tokens.url(req, res),
    tokens.status(req, res),
    tokens.res(req, res, 'content-length'), '-',
    tokens['response-time'](req, res), 'ms'
  ].join(' ')
})
```

It has `skip` option to skip logging, you must design your own strategy to skip or keep logging, for example you can check response status

```
var morgan = require('morgan')
morgan(function (tokens, req, res) {
  return [
    tokens.method(req, res),
    tokens.url(req, res),
    tokens.status(req, res),
    tokens.res(req, res, 'content-length'), '-',
    tokens['response-time'](req, res), 'ms'
  ].join(' ')
}, {
     skip: function (req, res) { return res.statusCode == 200 }
})
```

Comment: How can I use it if I can detect errors in the post handler? I don't want to log all the requests. Only the ones with some error.

Comment: Do you know how can I compose the original request from tokens? I don't care about response, error code or timing. Just the raw request.